# Change the data types of multiple columns through there names in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to change the data type of multiple columns at once in R only through there column names?

```
df
COlA   COLB COlC
sdf    12    34
sdsd   12    45
sdfa   45    34
```

COLB and COLC should be changed to integer at once by using there names and not through indexing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(across(c(COLB, COlC), as.integer))
```

Or if there are many columns, specify a range (`:`) if they are in the sequence

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(COLB:COlC, as.integer))
```

Or if only the first column needs to be skipped, can use `-`

```
 df %>%
    mutate(across(-COLA, as.integer))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `lapply`

```
nm1 <- names(df)[-1]
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], as.integer)
```

---

It is also possible to do this automatically with `type.convert`

```
type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```